# Inheritance with inner class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose we have a class named Outer which contains inner class called Inner.Then what will happen when we extends Outer class will that inner class will be inherited or not ? and what will happen when we declare that inner class as static and then extends Outer class. And lastly what will be case when we don't extends Outer class but we extends Inner class inside Outer class.

Comment: Showing some codes might heplful

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: two classes may be in the same file, But class can't be nested in another one

Comment: @user7790438 classes **can** be nested

Comment: Why don't you just write some code and find out?

Comment: This seems really theorical, so I guess reading some documentation about nested classes could help you understand them. Then of course, trying is always the solution